# glx error couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I tried installing openGL on my raspberry pi (libgl1-mesa.glx) but every time i try running glxinfo or rendering something i end up with an error:

`couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig`

I tried reconfiguring `xserver-xorg` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For enabling the open source graphics driver that provides OpenGL 2.0 support, there are a few more steps -- as is, you've put in the normal GL library (which is basically a wrapper that loads hardware drivers), but not the userspace or kernel side of the graphics driver.  When it doesn't find a hardware graphics driver it falls back to indirect GLX, but that fails because the X Server hasn't initialized a graphics driver either.

The easiest way to get all the necessary steps done is to use `sudo raspi-config` and choose the "Experimental GL driver", then reboot, which will both enable the kernel driver and install the necessary userspace packages.